# how can run command on redis with authorize in bash script?

Tags: redis

I have redis version 6.2.2 AUTH with username and password on centos 7

I want run command `flushall` with bash script

I tried send it with echo command but it failed

I do not know how can i send 2 command

How can i send `AUTH myusername mypassword` command and and after that `flushall` command with bash script?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue so I did some research and found a way to do this:
First of all, if you have a database with a requiredpass only and no configured users, you can simply use the flag **-a**  like this:

```
redis-cli -a mysupersecurepassword FLUSHALL
```

the problem with this is that it stores the complete command in your history (and with that the password), so you might want to go a step further:

```
 export REDISCLI_AUTH=mysupersecurepassword
```

here what we are doing is setting the enviroment variable called **REDISCLI_AUTH** to the password itself. Note that we use a leading space to tell linux that we do not want this to be stored in the history. Once we do that, there is no need to use the -a flag, you will be automatically authenticated.

But if you are having the same problem as me and need to use both username and password to authenticate, currently the only way to do this is to specify both within the uri using the **-u** flag:

```
redis-cli -u redis://user:password@host:port/dbnum: FLUSHALL
```

there is not very much you can do right now besides this. A possible solution for hiding your uri from your history might be to set it to an enviroment variable and then use that in the command:

```
 export REDIS_URI=redis://user:password@host:port/dbnum:
redis-cli -u $REDIS_URI FLUSHALL
```

Source: [REDIS-CLI documentation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/cli/#host-port-password-and-database)